# Microservice, module and error compilation: The injection point has the following annotations:

Tags: spring-boot, spring-modules

I spent my day trying to understand but I can't understand my problem.

I have 1 spring module (https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/) [I also have JPA in the sub module] and 2 microservices (A and B).

In microservice A, I arrive at @Autowired CountryRepository (which extends from JpaRepository) and which works very well, SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages = "**") with, I access my data and I can compile.

On microservice B, I did the same thing, I manage to access my data but impossible to compile:

```
****************************
FAILED TO START APPLICATION
****************************

Description:

Field countryRepository in * required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @ org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired (required = true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

I cannot understand or look for the error, how to unblock myself, I search again and again but I cannot understand why microservice B does not want to compile.

I use a POM Parent, and I was careful to put the following order:

```
<modules>
<module>sub module </module>
<module> microservice A </module>
<module> microservice B </module>
</modules>
```

So I hack, without understanding too much and sometimes I have different messages but always the compilation which fails

**Concretely, it is possible to use the Repositories of the sub-module in microservice A and B?**

Thank you for your attention and your help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Repositories of sub-modules.

You have to use @EnableJpaRepository in your main class and give the base package name there.

That's all, This will do the trick

Comment: Thank you ... But I must miss something ...
In the sub module, Application I have @ Service, @ SpringbootApplication @ EnableConfigurationProperties. In the @ Entity model and in the repository no anotation.

Comment: In microservice A and B, I put @SpringBootApplicationcanBasePackages = "") in an empty class with its own package. It worked very well for implementing a model object in the sub module, but since I want to use JPA in microservice A and B I have a lot of problems.

So I move @ SpringBootApplication (scanBasePackages = "") in the class of microservice A / B or I use @ Autowired, I added @ EnableJpaRepositories (suddenly I had an error that the bean is duplicated), this confirms the support for scanBasePackage, ... but

it still doesn't work and I don't understand why

Comment: can you share your snippet ?

Comment: ok thank you i will make a deposit during the day by recreating the project. But I also have a message from my IDE that says unmapped

Comment: I will have a look and get back to you

Comment: I am surprised that on my project or I have the concern (which have changed)
Description:

Field societeRepository in * required a bean of type '*' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @ org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired (required = true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type '*' in your configuration.

Comment: receive a message from IntelliJ "Spring configuration Check, Unmapped Spring configuration files found. Please configuration Spring facet or use 'Create Default Context' to add one including all unmapped files"

Comment: https://gitlab.com/Olivier4477/submodule I redid the manipulation on a new project, obviously it works but I let you watch. The project works, but ./mvnw package does not work

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at your repo and found few of the things are missing

In your CountryRepository.java class

```
@Repository 
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long> {
}
```

@Repository annotation is missing, you need to add that

Then in your Main Class of service A and service B you have to add as below

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepository("com.submodule.commun.modelandjpa.Repository")
public class ParentApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ParentApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

That's all..

Comment: Ok thanks but
1) Why ./mvnw package puts me:
[ERROR] * src / src / main / java / com / project / microservicea / Test.java: [6,46] package com.submodule.commun.modelandjpa.Model does not exist
[ERROR] * / src / main / java / com / project / microservicea / Test.java: [7,51] package com.submodule.commun.modelandjpa.Repository does not exist
[ERROR] * / src / main / java / com / project / microservicea / Test.java: [16,5] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class CountryRepository
[ERROR] location: class com.projet.microservicea.Test

Comment: [ERROR] * src / main / java / com / project / microservicea / Test.java: [20,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Country
[ERROR] location: class com.projet.microservicea.Test
[ERROR] * / src / main / java / com / project / microservicea / Test.java: [20,31] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Country
[ERROR] location: class com.projet.microservicea.Test

Comment: 2) 

microservice B works but not A ...
It's annoying when you head in the handlebars when faced with bugs like this;)
I have redone, I don't even know where I am